# Beaglebone Black update IP Address and subnet for USB0

Tags: networking, subnet, beaglebone

I'm looking for some guidance regarding updating the IP address for the BBB.  I have a BBB that I need to place remotely on my network. It's a custom BBB with no connections on it what so ever, other than the USB port. It has neither the Ethernet port or Wifi. The board boots via the emmc, not the sdcard. So I'm looking to find a way to use a USB-Ethernet adapter and connect it to the USB port.

So I need to update the IP address from 192.168.6.2, but more importantly I need to update the subnet so I'll be able to access it on my network.

It's obvious that I can update the information in the interfaces file, I've done this before with a Raspberry Pi. However what I'm concerned that if I go about making changes it's going to disable access completely and that's a risk I don't want to take. I just ordered a new board. I'll do some experimenting with the SD card, so I'll avoid bricking issues.

However, I was hoping to gain some insight as to what steps I should take. I've read that there are init scripts running at boot that setup and configure the USB0 as well.

Does anyone have any insight as to what steps I should take?

Michael

Comment: You're not clear as to how you boot this SBC. If you can boot from a SD card, then you don't have to worry about ever bricking the board. *"I've read that there are init scripts running at boot that setup and configure the USB0 as well."* -- Huh? Other than the Device Tree (?), there is no such thing as *"USB0"*.  USB is a bus, and not a user-accessible device.  A USB-to-Ethernet adapter should show up as the **eth0** device (assuming it's the first wired network device).

Comment: Just assign the new IP address to the NIC with`ip a add` (without deleting the existing one; was it even assigned to the NIC you are going to use though? As you said you are "looking to find a way to use" a USB-Ethernet adapter). A host machine can belong to more than one IP subnets. (It's just routes after all.)

Comment: @sawdust Hello, I'll update my original post to be clear regarding how the board boots. I'm using the emmc to boot the device. Also, USB0 is an ethernet connection that is setup for the board to communicate with a computer over USB. I understand that USB is a bus device, but as the board has no wifi or ethernet port, in this case, USB0 is an actual thing. When you pull up /etc/network/interfaces its the only network interface I can access.

Comment: @TomYan I'm not clear as to what your saying. In the past in order to use a static IP I've also needed to assign the subnet address so that its a recognizable device on my network.

Comment: Subnet address(es) will be added as route automatically by the kernel if you assign an address with a non-32 prefix. For example, `ip a add 192.168.6.2/24 dev eth0` would make the kernel assign the route `192.168.6.0/24`to `eth0`. And it's totally valid to have more than one address and subnet route assigned to one interface.

Comment: I wonder if your concern is mainly on changing (the gateway of) the default route, which is essentially used for "Internet connection".